# Soundless QEMU/VM win11

Tags: sound, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu, windows-11

I'm pretty much a novice when it comes to using LiGNUx and I've just gone through a painstaking process in order to get a Windows 11 virtual machine working with a totally legit ISO file without really knowing what I'm doing. Everything looks and works fine indeed, except that there is no sound! All of the virtual hardware is there and none of my sound sliders seem muted to me so I don't know what to do. I've tried rebooting as well as resetting and it didn't work. With every other solution I could find seemingly revolving around https://techpiezo.com/linux/enable-audio-in-qemu-virtual-machine/, which also didn't work.

`:~$ qemu-system-x86_64 -soundhw hda disk_image.qcow2 qemu-system-x86_64: disk_image.qcow2: Could not open 'disk_image.qcow2': No such file or directory`

```
:~$ qemu-system-x86_64 -soundhw all disk_image.qcow2

qemu-system-x86_64: disk_image.qcow2: Could not open 'disk_image.qcow2': No such file or directory
```

Afterwards I sought to create or find such a file or directory, since I'm pretty sure I had created one. But that sent me far down a unrelated rabbit that made me (momentarily) quit my searching and go here in order to finally humbly beseech Ubuntu for answers. I'm running **Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS** by the way.

Comment: "Hello kitties, " is what would've jokingly appeared in the starting sentence if it wasn't unexpectedly cutoff during publishing.